# Looking for a word for "flattening a tree"

Tags: tree

I'm wondering if there's an existing word to describe a process that I'm currently using.  I want to call it "flattening a tree" but I feel like there must be a better word or phrase.

input:

```
  |--D
--B
| |--C
|
A-E
|
| |--G
--F
  |--H
```

output:

```
[ [A, B, D]
  [A, B, C]
  [A, E]
  [A, F, G]
  [A, F, H] ]
```

Is there an established name for this process?

Comment: +1 - language is important to express ideas, point for the effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Path enumeration?

DFS traversal?

or my favourite

Tree arrayfication!

Comment: It does look like an enumeration of all the paths so 'path enumeration' would seem to fit.

Answer (score 4):

How about '**Hydrating**' (or **DeHydrating**) depending on the situation ?

Comment: I'm not sure a textbook would list that, but +1 for the actual submission of a 'name' :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you're just traversing the tree, while keeping a path to the current node.  As you visit a leaf, you print the complete path to the leaf.

I don't think there's a specific name, but it is not much different from a very simple traversal.

Answer (score 2):

[De-Normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalised) would seem to be best. Because indeed, if you notice your new structure you have redundant data, and it would appear to map directly to the conceptual idea.

Answer (score 2):

How about "Chainsawing"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called ***Serializing***

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across a wiki article on "[Disjoint Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Disjoint-set_data_structure&action=edit&section=2)" and the term it uses is "path compression."

Excerpt:

> ...
>   The second improvement, called path
>   compression, is a way of flattening
>   the structure of the tree whenever
>   Find is used on it. The idea is that
>   each node visited on the way to a root
>   node may as well be attached directly
>   to the root node; they all share the
>   same representative. To effect this,
>   as Find recursively traverses up the
>   tree, it changes each node's parent
>   reference to point to the root that it
>   found. The resulting tree is much
>   flatter, speeding up future operations
>   not only on these elements but on
>   those referencing them, directly or
>   indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a depth first search to capture every path from the root to a leaf.

Pseudo code:

```
global allPaths = []
R = root
currentPath = []
findPaths(R, currentPath)

findPaths(R, currentPath){
if R has no children,
allPaths.add( currentPath )

else
for each child C in R:
findPaths(C, currentPath + R)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but is there a word for a function that returns an array of paths?  There very well may not be.

Comment: You're "finding all paths to leaves". I don't think you can get a single word for it.

Comment: It is not a pathlist. It is a list of paths from the *root only*

Comment: Rootedpathlist. I can do this all day. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think of it as [coalescing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalescence_(computer_science)) portions of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is the tree and the output is the list of lists you quote, you are not actually looking for a phrase for the *process*, you're looking for a name for the *subroutine* you call. And the name of such a subroutine should be a description of what it *returns*.

How about `RootPathsOfLeaves` ? or some rearrangement thereof...